# Appending a cloned tr object into a tbody, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clone the children of `#secret_tr` into the `tbody` of the `.table`.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Key</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="secret_tr" style="display:none;">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>Bar</td>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This does not work apparently:

```js
var template  = $("#secret_tr").children().clone();
var tr        = template.find("table tbody tr");
$("table.table tbody").append(tr);
```

However, if I run this line instead the `td`s are getting appended, except now I am missing the `tr`:

```js
$("table.table tbody").append(tr.children());
```

Comment: what you want to append tr or tbody?

Comment: Your code is working fine, please update description of the issue to let us know whats not  working for you and have in mind that if there will be more then one matching elements to "table.table tbody" your tr will get appended into each of them

Comment: "*apparently*" - what makes you think it doesn't work?  Why "apparently"?  Your code, as presented [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/2fhpLgkz/)

Comment: Strange I swear it's not working in my end. But couldn't make sense of it, that's why I posted it here. Anyway, gues I'll have to close the question here and keep working on it in my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seams to work. I create a *reference* to the template. And with a *reference* to the `<tr>` I create a clone of the element. This clone can be appended `<tbody>`.

```js
var template = $("#secret_tr");
var tr = template.find("table tbody tr").clone();
$("table.table tbody").append(tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Key</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="secret_tr" style="display:none;">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>Bar</td>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```